# One-box is messing with my URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but I noticed today that if I [link to a room's info page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/33116630/history), it annoyingly one-boxes a link to the room, which is **not** a link to the info page!

That's it. I'm gonna pack up and leave! Such annoyance! But for the time being,

- Is this behavior expected? If so, what is the reason for changing the links?
- If this is really a bug since the responsible bot is not seeing parts of the URLs and ends up one-boxing, and hence linking to the wrong message, could this be fixed please? Worth pointing out that too much exposure to annoying things results in a higher blood pressure.

Comment: Wait, that's a message history link, not a link to a room's info. Can you clarify what issue you're seeing, please?

Comment: @AdamLear The link in this question links to a message that shows this bug: the message contains a room info link, which is rendered as a room link onebox.

Comment: @Adam I thought a link to the message's history demonstrates the issue very clearly. My text is a link to room info page, but it one-boxes as a link to the room.

Comment: Ahh, I thought the link in the post here was supposed to be an example of the link that was being one-boxed.

Comment: And if you'd started the link text two words earlier, it would have been entirely comprehensible. Isn't English wonderful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I'm dropping the /info part of the match; it is too confusing

---

It looks like this was very deliberate - we have a `(?:info/)?` in the regex that matches this. I wonder what the *right* thing to do is here. As it happens, the card *does* actually have the info link... it is just *really really* subtle:

[image]

And of course there is the explicit markdown link option, or posting additional text. I'm open to options on what we should do here. Provide the info page as the "main" link if the info link is posted? Don't onebox at all? Something else?

Comment: Oh man, that is indeed subtle. I guess not oneboxing works, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Just curious, did you zoom just for the sake of the screenshot, or is this your day-to-day resolution? :)

Comment: I'm a known anti-onebox activist so I would opt for **not** oneboxing if the info link is posted

Comment: @Shadow I use 4k high-DPI monitors, and the auto-scaling is pixel based. This makes it appear zoomed.

Comment: Whoa, no wonder you switched to SVG sprites... you must have suffered a lot before that! :-)